# SQL List Game Database By Most Likes

Tags: php, sql, mysql

So my site's main page display's applications for a PMP. Users can rate these apps with 'Like', 'Dislike', or 'Neutral/None' (every app is rated Neutral/None by default.)

On the main page I wanted to list the games by the highest difference (So it would take the total Like's and Dislike's then add them together.) I'm having difficulty making an SQL statement to do this correctly.

My tables structures are like this:

```
appinfo:
   id;
   name;
   genre;
   ...
```

`appinfo` basically holds all the metadata for the app. Nothing about the rating.

Next, I have the `apprating` table:

```
apprating:
   username;
   app_id;
   rating;
```

This is where all the ratings are stored. Ratings are stored as a -1 (Dislike), 0 (Neutral/None), and 1 (Like). I was hoping with this structure it would be easier to setup the whole statement. Can anyone help me out with writing one? I ended up writing a ridiculously long one that doesn't sort properly or display the rating number.

```
SELECT appinfo.title, appinfo.description, appinfo.username, appinfo.genre 
FROM appinfo 
LEFT JOIN appratings ON appinfo.id=appratings.app_id 
GROUP BY appinfo.id 
ORDER BY SUM(appratings.rating) DESC
```

Thanks SO MUCH for reading this through, just an SQL statement and correction on my evil SQL ways would be nice!

**UPDATE:**

So before there was a rating system, I would have my SELECT statement, then in PHP I'd `mysql_fetch_array`, then loop through and echo their details, effectively letting me do things such as:

```
...
<p class="description"><?php echo $gameinfo['description']; ?></p>
...
```

Which would grab the description of the game it was on and echo it. Now, description still works, but since I now have an odd system that involves using SUM with my Like's/Dislike's and a JOIN statement for appinfo.id and apprating.app_id, I'm now experiencing issues with

1. Echoing the ID of the current game, (echoing `$gameinfo['id']` doesn't echo anything.)
2. How can I get the SUM of the Like's/Dislike's and echo that?

**UPDATE 2**

The SQL statement allowed me to write `echo $gameinfo['totalscore']` to get the Like/Dislike differences and I just had to add `appinfo.id` to the SELECT to be able to echo the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GROUP BY clause needs to include all of the columns from the SELECT list that aren't being aggregated in some manner. You may happen to know that the description, title, and other details won't change for a particular app, but the database engine doesn't, so it needs 
to understand whether each selected column is fixed (as part of the GROUP BY) or aggregated (SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, etc.)

```
SELECT appinfo.title, appinfo.description, appinfo.username, appinfo.genre, 
    SUM(appratings.rating) AS totalscore
FROM appinfo LEFT JOIN appratings 
ON appinfo.id=appratings.app_id 
GROUP BY appinfo.title, appinfo.description, appinfo.username, appinfo.genre
ORDER BY totalscore DESC
;
```

Comment: I feel very stupid at this point because I'm realizing that my original question is wrong. This is correct though, I'm getting everything correctly. If you could help me on the issue I should've asked about that would be awesome as well. (Updating main post.)

Comment: The appinfo.id column wasn't included in your original SELECT, so it wouldn't be available to any PHP routines that consume that result set. Include appinfo.id in the SELECT clause and the GROUP BY clause, and it will be included in the result set that your PHP code will retrieve.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really need to think twice before I post things, and I found out your SQL statement let me echo totalscore (awesome!)

Answer (score 1):

See if you get the right results by changing the columns in the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT appinfo.title, appinfo.description, appinfo.username, appinfo.genre 
FROM appinfo 
LEFT JOIN appratings ON appinfo.id=appratings.app_id 
GROUP BY appinfo.title, appinfo.description, appinfo.username, appinfo.genre 
ORDER BY SUM(appratings.rating) DESC
```